# How to handle Python's threading.Thread exceptions?

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, python-multithreading

I'm using Selenium to run two Firefox instances and get specifics pages.
I'm loading the pages parallel using `threading.Thread` for each of them.
I also want to set timeout for maximum page loading time, with `browser.set_page_load_timeout()` in my code.

My whole code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from threading import Thread
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


class Test():
        def __init__(self):
            browser = webdriver.Firefox()

            def load_page(browser, url):
                browser.set_page_load_timeout(20)
                browser.get(url)

            t = Thread(target=load_page, args=(browser, 'http://www.stackoverflow.com', ))
            t.start()
            t.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        Test()
    except TimeoutException:
        print "timeout reached"
```

In spite of my `try except` declaration, i still got this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Temp\test_b.py", line 13, in load_page
    browser.get(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 213, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message: Timed out waiting for page load.
Stacktrace:
    at Utils.initWebLoadingListener/< (file:///c:/users/mgal/appdata/local/temp/tmpsasxck/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9010)
    at WebLoadingListener/e (file:///c:/users/mgal/appdata/local/temp/tmpsasxck/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:5114)
    at WebLoadingListener/< (file:///c:/users/mgal/appdata/local/temp/tmpsasxck/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:5122)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///c:/users/mgal/appdata/local/temp/tmpsasxck/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:621)
```

In conclusion, how can I catch the Timeout Exception out of the thread scope?
Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You should handle exception in the thread, so your function should look more or less like:

```
def load_page(browser, url):
    try:
        browser.set_page_load_timeout(20)
        browser.get(url)
    except TimeoutException:
        '''Handle me here'''
```

**EDIT:** What you actually request for is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


class Test():
        def __init__(self, queue, url):
            browser = webdriver.Firefox()

            def load_page(browser, url):
                try:
                    browser.set_page_load_timeout(20)
                    browser.get(url)
                except Exception as e:
                    queue.put(e)
                else:
                    queue.put('OK or whatever the result you want')

            t = Thread(target=load_page, args=(browser, url, ))
            t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ('http://www.stackoverflow.com', 'http://http://meta.stackoverflow.com/')
    queue = Queue()
    for url in urls:
        Test(queue, url)
    for i in range(len(urls)):
        result = queue.get()
        if isinstance(result, Exception):
            '''Handle exception preferably trying to determine the actual exception type'''
        else:
            '''Say cool cause everything is fine'''
```

Comment: You can catch the exception in the thread and pass along the exception object to the main thread using Queue. But first of all your code doesn't take any advantage of threads cause you always wait for a thread to join immediately after starting it. This way you will always get a sequential execution with worse performance than without threading.

Answer (score 0):

Threading children run in their own stack, so this is impossible without message/event passing.  You can use python's `Queue` library (which is thread-safe) and pass a queue object into your child function, using that as an event pool that the parent can handle.